# Why does node.js attach a string value in my array to another object in the array as true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm not sure why this is happening, but could use some input.

I have an object attached to the body of a POST request through jquery ajax. The object is similar to this example:

```
var dogData = {breeds: [{Dog: "Golden Retriever"}, "Rottweiler"]}
```

The AJAX request is this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/dog",
        data: dogData,
       })
```

On my server using Express + bodyparser:

```
app.post('/dogs', function(req, res){console.log(req.body)})
```

When I console.log the object:

```
{breeds: [{Dog: "Golden Retriever", Rottweiler: true}]}
```

I want the same object that I initially started out with to be returned from the server. Can someone explain why the string is attached to the previous object along with a boolean value?

Comment: You really should post real code. From what you did post, all that anybody can say is "something weird happened so there's probably a bug in your code."

Comment: I posted a little bit more but about how the request was made. I used the same object as the test variable. Just curious as to why this occurs and how to prevent this from happening without altering the data structure.

Comment: jQuery will assume that you want it to serialize the value of that `data` property in the ajax request as if it were a name/value set of form field properties. If you want to post a raw JSON string, you have to do things differently; exactly how depends on what your server expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jsonparser on your server and make your post with json content

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/dog",
        data: JSON.stringify(dogData),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
       })
```

Body parser parses urlencoded form data.

When you send your data it will be converted to:

```
breeds[0][Dog]=Golden+Retriever&breeds[Rottweiler];
```

When bodyparser parse it, because of there is no value on Rottweiler and it exists, it will be converted to "true"